# How to select attribute from joined tables with aggregate function?

Tags: sql, count, subquery, db2-express-c

These are three sample tables

Team

```
+-------------+-------------+
| TeamID      | TeamName    |             
+-------------+-------------+
| 11          | AA          | 
+-------------+-------------+
| 12          | BB          | 
+-------------+-------------+
| 13          | CC          |
+-------------+-------------+
```

Match

```
+-------------+
| MatchID     |        
+-------------+
| 1           |
+-------------+
| 2           | 
+-------------+
| 3           | 
+-------------+
```

Teammatch

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| TmID        | Team_ID     |  MatchID    |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 21          | 11          | 1           |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 22          | 11          | 2           |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 23          | 12          | 1           |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 24          | 13          | 2           |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 24          | 11          | 3           |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

The goal is to list the `TeamName` where they attend the matches more than one time like below:

```
+-------------+
| TeamName    |             
+-------------+
| AA          | 
+-------------+
```

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT TeamName 
FROM  Team T, Match M, Teammatch TM
WHERE T.TeamID = TM.TeamID AND
M.MatchID = TM.MatchID
......
```

But I really cannot figure out what to do next.

I have asked a similar question using `SELECT COUNT` before, but I do not really understand how to write the subquery here.

Comment: . . *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  Also, you should tag your questions with the database you are using.

Comment: Worth looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594953/sql-select-query-using-joins-group-by-and-aggregate-functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select query using joins, group by and aggregate functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594953/sql-select-query-using-joins-group-by-and-aggregate-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
    SELECT TeamName 
    FROM  Team T 
    JOIN  Teammatch TM ON T.TeamID = TM.TeamID
    JOIN  Match M ON M.MatchID = TM.MatchID
    GROUP BY TeamName
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Of course you could replace COUNT(*) with COUNT(DISTINCT M.MatchID) or similar.

Comment: I didn't see your answer because it was posted while I was typing mine. Both of our queries are nearly identical.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but a query like the one below should work. Group by TeamID to get one row per team, then aggregate the MatchID by count to get the number of matches for that team. Limit the results displayed with a HAVING statement on that count.

```
SELECT T.TeamName
FROM TeamMatch TM
    JOIN Match M ON M.MatchID = TM.MatchID
    JOIN Team T ON t.TeamID = TM.TeamID
GROUP BY TeamID
HAVING COUNT(MatchID) > 1
```